# C# SendKeys with WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

I want to use the SendKeys Methode to send keystrokes to a Webbrowser Control.
Think about a form with the Webbrowser control and a button.

If you click on the button the key "a" should be send to the webbrowsercontrol.
So i have informed myself and found the SendKey Methode. (the current code)

```
webBrowser1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("a");
```

Now my Problem! This is working but only every second click. So assume you click on the button the first time, then this wont work. When you click again on the button the a appears in the Webbrowser...

Any suggestions how this could be?

Comment: If you are using a webbrowser control, why bother with SendKeys if you have access to the entire DOM?

Comment: It should be some type of Onescreenkeyboard so different pages. Or is it possible to send something to the "active" DOM object of the browser.

Comment: Hihi, good hint!

I had to set the Focus with: webbrowser1.Document.Focus() then everything work as expected. 

(Not exaclty what you say, but found it with your help :))